# Como usar método de uma classe em uma activity?

Tags: android

Preciso usar o seguinte método, que localiza-se na classe VodPlayerAdapter em uma activity PlayerActivity:

```
 public void changeVideo(Video video, boolean playWhenReady) {
    finalizePlayer();
    this.video = video;
    VodSource.getInstance().getImageLoader().get(VodSource.URL_SERVER + this.video.getThumb(), new DescriptionImageListener(thumb));
    if(playWhenReady) {
        startVideo(playWhenReady);
    }
    else {
        rebuildThumb();
    }
}
```

Essa classe que é abstrata é instanciada duas vezes, uma em PlaylistActivity, que me interessa, desta forma:

```
vodPlayerAdapter = new VodPlayerAdapter(view, video, getWindow(), VodPlayerAdapter.PLAYLIST_MODE, true) {
        @Override
        public void refreshVideoInfor() {
            refreshVideoInfo();
        }
    };
```

O método acima está na PlaylistActivity que chama a PlayerActivity.
Quando clico em um botão, ele finaliza a PlaylistActivity, e neste momento inicializa a PlayerActivity...
Na PlaylistActivity eu crio uma instância do objeto da minha classe VodPlayerAdapter, consigo usar seus métodos etc, porém nesta outra activity não consigo mais, e por ser um adapter com informações do estado anterior que estava na PlaylistActivity, creio que não posso novamente dar new só para usar onde quero, até tentei e dá erro.
Dessa forma, gostaria de saber alguma forma que poderia usar este método da classe VodPlayerAdapter na Playeractivity sem criar nova instância.

Answer (score 0):

Se você só quer usar o método, instancie uma classe que herde de `VodPlayerAdapter`, implemente o método desta forma

```
@Override
public void refreshVideoInfor() {
      refreshVideoInfo();
}
```

E instancie essa classe tanto em `PlaylistActivity` e `PlayerActivity`. Ambas vão executar o mesmo método. Se o problema são os parâmetros, passe-os adequadamente da `PlaylistActivity` para `PlayerActivity` e os passe nesta classe filha de `VodPlayerAdapter`.